# Flutter - local notification : issue's said Unhandled exception

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

i have message error that say unhandled exception for notification, but i has do that, so what a issues specific for this?
i got stuck with this problem, i've using real device for that and normal signal but this i'm always get this error, in this below i will write my code

> root file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

import 'ui/detail_page.dart';
import 'ui/home_page.dart';
import 'utils/notification_helper.dart';

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final NotificationHelper _notificationHelper = NotificationHelper();

  await _notificationHelper.initNotifications(flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin);
  _notificationHelper.requestIOSPermissions(flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin);

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: HomePage.routeName,
      routes: {
        HomePage.routeName: (context) => HomePage(),
        DetailPage.routeName: (context) => DetailPage(),
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

> notificaiton helper

```
final selectNotificationSubject = BehaviorSubject<String?>();
final didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject =
    BehaviorSubject<ReceivedNotification>();

class NotificationHelper {
  static const _channelId = '01';
  static const _channelName = 'channel_01';
  static const _channelDesc = 'talktech_channel';

  static NotificationHelper? _instance;
  NotificationHelper._internal() {
    _instance = this;
  }

  factory NotificationHelper() => _instance ?? NotificationHelper();

  Future<void> initNotifications(
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin) async {
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap/ic_launcher');

    var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
        requestAlertPermission: false,
        requestBadgePermission: false,
        requestSoundPermission: false,
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
            (int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {
          didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject.add(ReceivedNotification(
              id: id, title: title, body: body, payload: payload));
        });

    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: (String? payload) async {
      if (payload != null) {
        log('notification payload' + payload);
      }
      selectNotificationSubject.add(payload);
    });
  }


  Future<void> showNotification(
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        _channelId, _channelName,
        channelDescription: _channelDesc,
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        ticker: 'ticker');

    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();

    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      'plain title',
      'plain body',
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'plain notification',
    );
  }

  void requestIOSPermissions(
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestPermissions(
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true,
        );
  }
    
  void configureDidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject(
      BuildContext context, String route) {
    didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject.stream
        .listen((ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {
      await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
          title: receivedNotification.title != null
              ? Text(receivedNotification.title!)
              : null,
          content: receivedNotification.body != null
              ? Text(receivedNotification.body!)
              : null,
          actions: [
            CupertinoDialogAction(
              isDefaultAction: true,
              child: Text('Ok'),
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
                await Navigator.pushNamed(context, route,
                    arguments: receivedNotification);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  void configureSelectNotificationSubject(BuildContext context, String route) {
    selectNotificationSubject.stream.listen((String? payload) async {
      await Navigator.pushNamed(context, route,
          arguments: ReceivedNotification(payload: payload));
    });
  }
}
```

> Homepage

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../main.dart';
import '../utils/notification_helper.dart';
import '../widget/custom_button.dart';
import 'detail_page.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = "/";

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final NotificationHelper _notificationHelper = NotificationHelper();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _notificationHelper.configureSelectNotificationSubject(
        context, DetailPage.routeName);
    _notificationHelper.configureDidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject(
        context, DetailPage.routeName);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    selectNotificationSubject.close();
    didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Simple Notification'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Wrap(
            alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
            runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
            runSpacing: 20,
            children: <Widget>[
              CustomButton(
                  text: 'show notif',
                  onPressed: () async {
                    await _notificationHelper
                        .showNotification(flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin);
                  })                
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


[![issue's][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KULim.png
```